# using xmlHTTPRequest for opening a secure application in a new window

Tags: javascript, web-applications, xmlhttprequest

We have a requirement where we want the ability to launch a new application (NewApp) from the base app (BaseApp). The login credentials for BaseApp and the NewApp are same since they use the same identity store.
BaseApp and NewApp are on different tech stacks, both being web applications. they are hosted on different servers.
NewApp provides basic Auth for web access.

How can I use java script to launch NewApp from links on my BaseApp. I want to be able to inject Basic Auth credentials.

I have tried using xmlHTTPRequest, but it appears to be geared more towards calling REST services and processing the fetched data rather than launching URLs.
using java script window.open(url) does not let me inject authorization header!

anything else I can explore ?

Additional Info:
The session cookie for BaseApp is not applicable for NewApp. When we first complete Basic Auth on the BaseApp, it generates a new Session Cookie which needs to be used.
Through xhr we are able to call the URL (with Basic Auth) for the NewApp. This returns a response with a session cookie.
The problem that I am unable to figure out is, how to render the response on a new window/tab on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is calling the new window with following url

```
http://<user>:<pass>@newapp
```

but this is not a good solution because you see credentials in plain text. You should better try one of the following solutions:

1. If you use a session cookie it's often possible to append it to the url like `http://newapp?JSESSIONID=kjasbfkji877786sdf`.

   1. Either you can use the same Cookie from your base app (that should not be possible if the applications are on different machines)
   2. Create XMLHttpRequest calling NewApp and authentication via BasicAuth. The response header should contain the required session cookie from the other server. Then you can call NewApp with the required cookie.
2. If you have no session cookie you could also try the second solution (XHR) because if a session is created it is also stored in the browser and the browser can manage session handling itself.

So in cases 1.2. and 2. you should do the following:

```
var XMLReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
XMLReq.open("GET", "url", asynchronous?, "user", "password");
XMLReq.send(null);
```

In case 1.2. you need to provide an additional handler for a succeeding call:

```
XMLReq.onload = function() {
    window.open('http://NewApp?JSESSIONID='+XMLReq.getResponseHeader('Cookie')); 
    // note that 'JSESSIONID' depends on your backend implementation, this example is made for java backend
}
```

In case 2. it's simply

```
XMLReq.onload = function() {
    window.open('http://NewApp'); 
}
```

The best solution would be OAuth or OpenID in this case but that depends on your usecase and your system environment and requires maybe a more complex backend implementation if there is currently no support for OAuth or OpenID.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am not able to use xhr.getResponseHeader("Cookie"); This gives an error: Refused to get unsafe header "Cookie".

Comment: In my case the session cookie for BaseApp is not applicable for NewApp. When we first complete Basic Auth on the BaseApp, it generates a new Session Cookie which needs to be used.
Through xhr we are able to call the URL (with Basic Auth) for the NewApp. This returns a response with a session cookie.
The problem that I am unable to figure out is, how to render the response on a new window/tab on the browser.

Comment: open a new window is realized with `window.open(url)` in javascript